# Command to get HBase table owner

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

Is there any command to get complete description about hbase table such as owner, database, modified time, etc.

In hive, i can get those information using

`desc formatted tablename`

But in hbase `desc 'tablename'` shows size, version, replication_scope, etc.

I want to get owner details of hbase table.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `desc extended tablename`

Comment: Getting exception "undefined method extended"

Comment: what's the version of hbase you use? I can get the owner just run 'desc tablename' by hbase 1.2.0

Comment: I am using 1.1.3 version. Is 1.2.0 released with stable version?

Comment: @Kumar yes, you can even download http://mirrors.cnnic.cn/apache/hbase/1.2.1/, i'm actually using cloudera release https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-1.2.0-cdh5.7.0.tar.gz. Maybe you should make sure the access control related configuration is added at your server side.

Answer (score 1):

**First, add `access control` related config to hbase-site.xml :**

```
   <property>
      <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
   </property>
```

You can follow the instructions [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-3-2/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_8_3.html), maybe have to restart hbase after the modification.

**Then, set the owner of one table, and describe it**

```
hbase(main):007:0> alter 'MyTable', {OWNER => 'sel-fish'}
Updating all regions with the new schema...
1/1 regions updated.
Done.
0 row(s) in 1.9980 seconds

hbase(main):008:0> desc 'MyTable'
Table MyTable is ENABLED
MyTable, {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {METADATA => {'OWNER' => 'sel-fish'}}
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'cf', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '2147483647', TTL => '500 SECONDS (8 MINUTES 20 SECO
NDS)', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
1 row(s) in 0.0300 seconds
```